Error: 17: API: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}
I am using this npm react-native-google-fit and I am getting error here while getting stepdata


[Error: 17: API: Fitness.CLIENT is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}]

GoogleFit.getDailySteps({
      startDate,
      endDate,
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('Data:', res);
        // Process the data as needed
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error fetching  data', err);
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to fetch data.');
      });



